# Programmatically find COM and LPT address in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port, lpt

I am using Matlab to program an experiment.

In particular, I am using these lines of code to read and send triggers to an external device:

```
    ioObj = io64;
    status = io64(ioObj);
    io64(ioObj,portWriteAddress,0);
```

I have found the value for 'portWriteAddress by navigating to:
Device manager -> Ports -> LPT1 -> Resources. Then, in Resources there is an entry called I/O Range/ Settings with a code like 02S7 - 02SS (something like that).

Then I have converted it from Hex to Dec and put it in the line above.

THE PROBLEM IS: I am running this experiment on several different computers. Is there a way to programmatically find this range (or address) information fromMatlab?

Thank you all for your time.

Gluce

P.S.
The OS that I am using is Windows 7 (it should be soon updated to windows 10).
The computers are running either Matlab 2015b or 2016b.